# How can I map from a collection to a collection property?

Tags: mapstruct

Let's say I have following mapping target.

```java
class Some {

    private List<Other> others;
}
```

How can I map from an `Iterable` of `Other`s to the `others` property?

Can I do this?

```java
@Mapper
interface SomeMapper {

    // map source to target.others
    Some mapOthers(Iterable<? extends Other> source, @MappingTarget Some target);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to map a source parameter to a target property then you should defined `@Mapping` if the source parameter does not match the name of the target property. In this case something you could do something like:

```
@Mapper
interface SomeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "others", source = "source")
    Some mapOthers(Iterable<? extends Other> source, @MappingTarget Some target);
}
```